How to set an index of a fixed size `String[]` in vyper?
I have a String[] in vyper:
my_string: String[5] = "hello"

I would like to change the h to a p. How can I do that on this array?
my_string[0] = "p" # Cannot do this in Vyper


It's a bit ugly, but you can do something like this:
@external
def set_index(my_string: String[5], index: uint256, chunk_to_set: String[1]) -> String[5]:
    my_string_length: uint256 = len(my_string)
    buffer: String[11] = concat(slice(my_string, 0, index), chunk_to_set, slice(my_string, index+1, my_string_length - 1 - index))
    return abi_decode(abi_encode(buffer), (String[5]))

Here is a full example you can try in remix:
my_string: public(String[5])

@deploy 
def __init__():
    self.my_string = "hello"

@external
def set_index(index: uint256, chunk_to_set: String[1]):
    my_string_length:uint256 = len(self.my_string)
    buffer: String[11] = concat(slice(self.my_string, 0, index), chunk_to_set, slice(self.my_string, index+1,my_string_length - 1 - index))
    self.my_string = abi_decode(abi_encode(buffer), (String[5]))

Credit to trocher
